# Gem file with git remote failing on heroku push

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku, bundler

I have the following line in my gemfile:

```
gem 'client_side_validations', :git => "git@github.com:Dakuan/client_side_validations.git", :branch => "master", ref: '2245b4174ffd4b400d999cb5a2b6dccc0289eb67'
```

The repo it's pointing at is public and I can run bundle install / update locally just fine. When I try to push to Heroku I get the following error:

> ```
>    Fetching git@github.com:Dakuan/client_side_validations.git
>    Host key verification failed.
>    fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
>    Git error: command `git clone 'git@github.com:Dakuan/client_side_validations.git' "/tmp/build_1xa9f06n4k1cu/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/cache/bundler/git/client_side_validations-56a04875baabb67b5f8c192c6c6743df476fd90f" --bare --no-hardlinks` in directory /tmp/build_1xa9f06n4k1cu has failed.
> ```
>
> !
>    !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
>    !
>    !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/rails app

Anyone got any ideas about what's going on here?

Answer (score 153, accepted):

Use this GitHub URL instead: `git://github.com/Dakuan/client_side_validations.git`

The `git@github.com:…` URL is the writable SSH version, which requires authentication with an SSH key connected to a GitHub account that has write access to the repository.

The `git://github.com/…` URL is the public, read-only version.

Since the gem you're using is in a public GitHub repository, you can also use this shorthand in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'client_side_validations', :github => 'Dakuan/client_side_validations'
```

See the [Bundler Git documentation](http://bundler.io/v1.3/git.html) for more information.

Comment: Yep, that's the badger. Thanks for your help!

Comment: don't forget to run a bundle install to update your gemfile.lock and commit your changes after changing to github public url

Comment: I didn't expect such a simple resolution to this problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A late second answer, as I ran into some confusing output from Heroku's build logs which stumped me for a while.

If you have multiple Github hosted gems in your Gemfile, and one of them is inaccessible (in my case, I had accidentally pointed to a private repo of mine), the build logs throw an error like `Username not found` or `Repository not found` for *all* the Github hosted gems - even those that are available.