# Bundler fails for deploying using elastic beanstalk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am getting following error when trying to deploy a `rails 4.2.1` app on ec2 using elastic beanstalk

```
on't run Bundler as root. Bundler can ask for sudo if it is needed, and
installing your bundle as root will break this application for all non-root
users on this machine.
Fetching source index from https://rubygems.org/
Fetching git@github.com:bokmann/font-awesome-rails.git
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
Retrying git clone 'git@github.com:bokmann/font-awesome-rails.git' "/var/app/ondeck/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0/cache/bundler/git/font-awesome-rails-aa9211906101215f2656ef38ba0c26146ba4c6bc" --bare --no-hardlinks --quiet due to error (2/3): Bundler::Source::Git::GitCommandError Git error: command `git clone 'git@github.com:bokmann/font-awesome-rails.git' "/var/app/ondeck/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0/cache/bundler/git/font-awesome-rails-aa9211906101215f2656ef38ba0c26146ba4c6bc" --bare --no-hardlinks --quiet` in directory /var/app/ondeck has failed.
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
Git error: command `git clone 'git@github.com:bokmann/font-awesome-rails.git'
"/var/app/ondeck/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0/cache/bundler/git/font-awesome-rails-aa9211906101215f2656ef38ba0c26146ba4c6bc"
--bare --no-hardlinks --quiet` in directory /var/app/ondeck has failed.

2014-07-13 15:16:48,672 [ERROR] (4743 MainThread) [directoryHooksExecutor.py-33] [root directoryHooksExecutor error] Script  /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/10_bundle_install.sh failed with returncode 11
```

and `.ebextensions/ruby.config` looks like this

```
# Install git in order to be able to bundle gems from git
packages:
yum:
git: []
patch: []

commands:
# Run rake with bundle exec to be sure you get the right version
add_bundle_exec:
test: test ! -f /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/.post-provisioning-complete
cwd: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre
command: perl -pi -e 's/(rake)/bundle exec $1/' 11_asset_compilation.sh 12_db_migration.sh
# Bundle with --deployment as recommended by bundler docs
#   cf. http://gembundler.com/v1.2/rationale.html under Deploying Your Application
add_deployment_flag:
test: test ! -f /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/.post-provisioning-complete
cwd: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre
command: perl -pi -e 's/(bundle install)/$1 --deployment/' 10_bundle_install.sh
# Vendor gems to a persistent directory for speedy subsequent bundling
make_vendor_bundle_dir:
test: test ! -f /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/.post-provisioning-complete
command: mkdir /var/app/support/vendor_bundle
# Store the location of vendored gems in a handy env var
set_vendor_bundle_var:
test: test ! -f /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/.post-provisioning-complete
cwd: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support
command: sed -i '12iexport  
EB_CONFIG_APP_VENDOR_BUNDLE=$EB_CONFIG_APP_SUPPORT/vendor_bundle' envvars
# The --deployment flag tells bundler to install gems to vendor/bundle/, so
# symlink that to the persistent directory
symlink_vendor_bundle:
test: test ! -f /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/.post-provisioning-complete
cwd: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre
command: sed -i 's/\(^cd $EB_CONFIG_APP_ONDECK\)/\1\nln -s $EB_CONFIG_APP_VENDOR_BUNDLE .\/vendor\/bundle/' 10_bundle_install.sh
# Don't run the above commands again on this instance
#   cf. http://stackoverflow.com/a/16846429/283398
z_write_post_provisioning_complete_file:
cwd: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support
command: touch .post-provisioning-complete%
```

I am using a 64 bit Amazon Linux server and trying to install using `ruby-2.0.0` and `passenger`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this is failing because in your ebextensions you are running `bundle install --deployment`. Is there a reason you want to use the --deployment flag. Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3681411/161628.
If your usecase does not need the --deployment flag, I would suggest don't use it.

You can locally package your app dependencies using vendor/cache using the approach documented in [this](http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/application-management/post/Tx2XVRWSS4E971S/Locally-Packaging-Gem-Dependencies-for-Ruby-Applications-in-Elastic-Beanstalk) blog.

Can you update the question with the contents of your Gemfile. Are you are using git@ URLs in your Gemfile? You might want to use URLs like "git://github.com:bokmann/font-awesome-rails.git" in case you have "git@github.com:bokmann/font-awesome-rails.git" in your Gemfile.
Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11558814/161628) answer.

Comment: there is no particular reason to use --deployment flat. I removed it. testing again

Comment: So what finally worked? Removing deployment flag or changing git url?

Comment: I have the same issue. The problem is I have one gem referenced to relative path. Can you help how can I fix it?

gem 'pushmeup', :path=>'vendor/pushmeup'